# SASS/SCSS variables to CSS is possible?

Tags: html, css, variables, sass, frontend

When trying to display in CSS the SASS variable that I declared, I don't get the variable itself in the CSS output file, but the value given to the variable.

To be more clear, this is what I get:

SCSS/SASS input

```
$gray__background: #2d2d2d;

:root {
    --gray__background: #{$gray__background};
}

body{
  background-color: $gray__background;
}
```

CSS "output"

```
:root {
 --gray__background: #2d2d2d;
}

body{
 background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
```

That's what I was expecting to get:

CSS "output"

```
:root {
  --gray__background: #2d2d2d;
}
body{
  background-color: var(--gray__background);
}
```

Short story: I want to know if the result in the CSS "auto generated" file `background-color: var(--gray__background);`, instead of `background-color: #2d2d2d;` is possible to achieve.

I use the [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) extension for VSCode.

Sorry if my question is a little bit vague. I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:root` variables are being declared in the SCSS, but are not being used, so they wouldn't show up on the CSS output.
It looks like you'll have to use `--gray__background` in the SCSS rather than `$gray__background` so it becomes: `background-color: var(--gray__background);`
.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did help! It looks like I was declaring the :root folder in SCSS folder and not really making use of it.

Comment: @BrendonMedeiros if his answer helped you, hit the checkmark next to his answer to give him credit for it

Comment: @Brad Sure thing I'll do! I was just waiting to see if other users would come with different solutions and explanations.